# Authenticated SMTP relay not working if from and user don't match

Tags: exchange-2013

We have an Exchange 2016 and we have this issue:

- on some of our customers servers we must configure some email alerts that are sent through a SMTP connector (with STARTTLS and AUTH-LOGIN enabled)
- the destination address is To: `people@customerdomain.com`
- the SMTP user is `alert@ourcompany.com`
- if we specify `From: alert@ourcompany.it` then everything is fine
- **but** if we specify `From: alertservice@customerdomain.com` our server reports this error

:

```
 [S] 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
 ....
 550 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
```

The error occurs both if we use a FrontendTransport receive connector or a HubTransport receive connector.

We searched for a solution but we didn't find anything.

> Is there a setting that allows to use any `From:` address when relaying mail for authenticated SMTP users?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is the mail server for all these domains, it's possible for example to add all these addresses as `proxyAddresses` in AD, e.g. `smtp:alertservice@example.com`. If the address already belongs to another account, the account should have a *send on behalf* / *send as* permission for that address.

If your server is not a mail server for these domains, please consider that it may not be listed as a permitted sender in SPF, causing these messages to be rejected or treated as spam. Therefore, it may be a better idea to use an email address of your own domain; the one that didn't have this problem in the first place.